# Discord bot not answering on my server(python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have an issue with my discord bot. I have restarted a new bot in python (had already one in javascript) but I cannot make it listen and answer in my server. It can answer when I do the basic command via direct messaging but that's it.

Here is my code :

```
import discord
import logging
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.guilds = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)



# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='bot.log', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    logging.info('Bot is ready.')
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == '!hello':
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
        logging.info(f'"{message.author}" sent "!hello" in "{message.channel}"')
        print(f'"{message.author}" sent "!hello" in "{message.channel}"')

client.run('My-Token-Obviously

')
```

Here, I'm just trying to do a typical hello command. I have also tried by integrating this line of code : `channel = client.get_channel(My-id-channel)` but it does not change anyting.

Do you guys see any error in my code? Or anything that could be improve to get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Default intents does not enable `message_content`. You can read more on intents [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.default).

`on_message` event requires `intents.messages` to be enabled. Can also read about that in the [doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.default).

Give this a try and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add messages to your intents: `intents.message_content = True` as you do for guilds.

Besides, I strongly recommand to use this tutorial:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html

And this documentation to make a bot instance, because a Bot instance can do more things than a Client instance: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html